# Firebase phone autenticacion

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-auth

Tengo una app donde el usuario se registra con su numero de telefono  usando FirebasAuth... La idea es generar una conexion automaticamente.. Como puedo hacer para que cuando el usuario vuelve a usar la app (aun la app esta cerrada), no tiene que registrar de nuevo? que lo manda directamente al pagina Inicial al verificar que este numero ya existe..
Ahi esta mi codigo funciona bien.......
desde Ya muchas gracias

```
private void verifySignInCode(){
    String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, code);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       //here you can open new activity
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Loading.this,Welcome.class);
                             startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Incorrect Verification Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
private void sendVerificationCode(){
    String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();

    if(phone.isEmpty()){
        editTextPhone.setError("Phone number is required");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(phone.length() < 10 ){
        editTextPhone.setError("Please enter a valid phone");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phone,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        codeSent = s;
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

En el Activity que tengas seteado como launcher deberas verificar si hay un usuario logeado o no.

Solo debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
      //No estas logeado, debes ir a la pantalla de login
      //Metele un finish() a este Activity para que no puedas volver dando back una vez en la pantalla de login
    }else{
      //Estas logeado!
    }
  }
}
```